# How to send twitter data into SQL database using R

Tags: mysql, r, twitter

I would like to extract twitter data for more than one day. I have done that but unfortunately the file is large. Putting this data into SQL would decrease the file size significantly. It would also help a lot in the post-hoc analysis. 
I am not going to post the needy greedy detail that goes on top of this code. I wanna save each tweet and put it into database.

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user = 'root', password = 'xxxx', dbname = 'Tweets_Science', host = 'localhost')

dbListTables(con)

filterStream(file.name= dbWriteTable(con,"test"), track=c("dieoff"), timeout=10, oauth=twitCred)

Error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"MySQLConnection", "character", "missing"’
```

The reason for my questioning is that, I have a large and continuously growing data. I want to store such data. Hence, I was storing this data as csv file. Is it better to save it as csv or in database using MySQL? If the question is still not clear then please let me know

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work?

Comment: Following is the error that I get when I enter dbConnect function. Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown MySQL Server Host 'host' (11004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.package("RMySQL")

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='PASSWORD', dbname='test', host='localhost')

dbListTables(mydb)

dbWriteTable(mydb, name='table_name', value=parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("Climate"), timeout=10, oauth=my_oauth)))
```